# How to concatenate unicode strings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, string-concatenation

I have a unique situation where I need to concatenate rows based on 2 groups. The other trick is that the concatenation must be able to display bullets and add a line feed. This is what my business is requesting. I should also add the final destination will be Excel. I’ve tested exporting to Excel with SSIS using data that has bullets and line feeds and this piece does work.

How to go from:

```
pk   orgnl_pk   type   text
1    1          one    • Line One
2    1          one    • Line Two
3    1          one    • Line Three
4    1          two    • Line One
7    3          one    • Line One
8    3          two    • Line One
9    3          two    • Line Two
```

To:

```
orgnl_pk    type    text
1           one     • Line One
                    • Line Two
                    • Line Three
1           two     • Line One
3           one     • Line One
3           two     • Line One
                    • Line Two
```

Comment: this should be done in the presentation layer, not at the database level

Comment: I agree with @Lamak here. The business may be requesting it to look like that and you need to provide that. But the database should return the data to your application and then you format it.

Comment: I agree with both of you, and this was my initial response as well. However, the current tools and security level available to us within the corporation require this be done. I know it can be done, it’s just a matter of how. I should also add the final destination will be Excel. I’ve tested exporting to Excel with SSIS using data that has bullets and line feeds and this piece does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lamak pointed out, this is best left to the presentation layer, but if you must do it in sql for now... then this uses the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select 
    orgnl_pk
  , [type]
  , [text]=stuff(
        (
        select char(10) +i.[text]
          from t as i
          where i.orgnl_pk = t.orgnl_pk
            and i.[type]=t.[type]
          order by i.pk 
        for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,0,'')
from t
group by orgnl_pk, [type]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GPFIMO37322

returns:

```
+----------+------+--------------+
| orgnl_pk | type |     text     |
+----------+------+--------------+
|        1 | one  | • Line One   |
|          |      | • Line Two   |
|          |      | • Line Three |
|        1 | two  | • Line One   |
|        3 | one  | • Line One   |
|        3 | two  | • Line One   |
|          |      | • Line Two   |
+----------+------+--------------+
```

---

Update for character (0x0007) :

```
select 
    orgnl_pk
  , [type]
  , [text]=replace(stuff(
        (
        select char(10)+replace(i.[text],nchar(0x0007),'$BEL$')
          from t as i
          where i.orgnl_pk = t.orgnl_pk
            and i.[type]=t.[type]
          order by i.pk 
        for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,''),'$BEL$',nchar(0x0007))
from t
group by orgnl_pk, [type]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @SqlZim. I substituted both t tables with my table name. Is this correct? I get this error 'FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x0007) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive'

Comment: @B.C. you could replace it with a temporary string and replace it back after the `for xml`. I updated the answer with a workaround for that. -- Or just remove it as shown here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/107238/43889

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim! I really like the idea of replacing it to a temporary string. This is great!